# CodeIgniter OpenSSL error sending mails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, openssl

I'm getting the following error when trying to send emails with CodeIgniter ON WINDOWS:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: failed loading cafile stream: `‪C:\OpenSSL\cert\cacert.pem'
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 2055
```

Also i'm getting these errors:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 2055
```

And:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 2055
```

This code was working before, but started throwing this error after I upgraded my php version to 5.6

- phpinfo() shows OpenSLL is enabled.
- phpinfo() shows openssl.cafile is    set to:
  ‪C:\OpenSSL\cert\cacert.pem which is the location pointed by 
  my php.ini, and is where I left the cacert.pem certificate.
- I'm using the cacert.pem from: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
- Im using CodeIgniter 3.1.6 over PHP 5.6, over WINDOWS 10

**EDIT:**

Following the advice of other posts, I decided to put my dirty hands on CodeIgniter's Email class, and replaced the calls to **fsockopen()** with **stream_socket_client()**:

```
$context = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
        'ciphers' => 'RC4-MD5',
        'cafile' => '‪C:/OpenSSL/cert/cacert.pem',
    ]]);

//$this->_smtp_connect = fsockopen($ssl.$this->smtp_host, $this->smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->smtp_timeout);

$this->_smtp_connect = stream_socket_client($ssl.$this->smtp_host.':'.$this->smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->smtp_timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

However, I'm still getting the same 3 errors of above.

The fact that both **fsockopen()** and **stream_socket_client()** throw the same error about not loading the cafile is really weird.

Comment: localhost or production server?

Comment: localhost. and production server, but it is also running windows. I wan't to solve the problem for my dev machine (windows 10) and then try the same solution with the production server (windows server 2012)

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962061/2275490

Comment: If I followed that solution I would have to modify CodeIgniter's  Email Library. (See, it's not "my" code the one calling fsockopen()) I don't think the problem's there. I'm using the last version of CodeIgniter, and PHP 5.6, which is already old. I believe CodeIgniter Email library should work with PHP 5.6.  I mean, I could do that, but that would be one of the last solutions I would try.

Comment: OK, I finally decided to put my dirty hands on CodeIgniter's Email Class.
I changed the call fsockopen, with stream_socket_client and I'm still getting the exact 3 same errors. The first error of  "failed loading cafile" freaks me out.

Comment: I think it shouldn't come from C:\etc, but from a relative server link

Comment: just tried all that. tried: 1. with an "absolute" link '/OpenSSL/cert/cacert.pem' and 2. placing the cacert.pem in a folder inside my codeigniter project, with a relative link 'cert/cacert.pem'. none worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160032/discussion-between-vickel-and-mauricio-ubilla-carvajal).